# Git feature branch with dependency on another feature branch

Tags: git, git-flow

In my project, I have 2 tickets for new features. Created `feature-#1` branch from `develop` branch and finished the code implementation for the first ticket and want to start the second ticket.

My problem is the `feature-#1` branch is still in code review, but my second ticket is dependent on `feature-#1` branch, so I can't start the next feature since I'm waiting the `feature-#1` branch to be merged to `develop` branch before creating the `feature-#2` brand from `develop` branch.

Any advice or best practices for this?

Comment: Just branch `feature-#2` from `feature-#1` and rebase it on `develop` after `feature-#1` merges?

Comment: @larsks what if ```feature-#1``` removed after merging into develop?

Comment: That would be the second part of my previous comment ("rebase it on `develop` after `feature-#1` merges).

Answer (score 1):

The concept that @BerkayBerapi talks about is correct, however I want to go a little bit further into the subject. In this case, it's a little simpler because you are in control of the base feature branch... but there might be other situations where you have to be more careful. Suppose you start `feature2` from `feature1`..... and start coding and committing. That's all good. But what happens if you get reviews in `feature1` and you need to *rebase* `feature1`? Then you could say.... ok, I rebase `feature2` as well.

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase origin/main
git checkout feature2
git rebase origin/main
```

Is this correct? Not really because you would have *duplicate* revisions for the original revisions of `feature1`, right? In order for this to be made correctly, it requires a little more effort.

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase origin/main
# assuming that feature2 is made up of 4 _straight_ revisions after feature1
git rebase --onto feature1 feature2~4 feature2 # rebase only the last 4 revisions of feature2
```

This is *specially* true when you are using a branch that you don't control. It might be rebased, squashed, get its history rewritten, whatever... even refactored.... whatever happens with it, you need to make sure to *not* move around revisions of `feature1` when playing with `feature2`.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a new branch based on any branch.

```
git checkout feature1
// create feature2 branch basing on feature1
git checkout -b feature2
// after feature 1 gets merged
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout feature2
git merge develop
```